# Random SSL handshake error when connecting to ElastiCache with ioRedis

Tags: node.js, ssl, redis, amazon-elasticache, ioredis

I am attempting to connect to an ElastiCache cluster that is encrypted in transit from a node script using ioRedis. Sometimes my script works, other times I get `Error: 140736319218624:error:140940E5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1216:`

Here is all of my code:

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var nodes = [{
host: 'clustercfg.name.xxxxxx.region.cache.amazonaws.com',
port: '6379',
}];
var cluster = new Redis.Cluster(nodes,{
redisOptions: {
    tls: {}
}});

cluster.set('aws', 'test');
cluster.get('aws', function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
    cluster.disconnect()
});
```

Comment: "ssl handshake failure" could be many things. It will be difficult to debug without more logging on both sides. Could it be that the hostname resolves to different IP addresses sometimes and you hit different servers?

Comment: The other side is an AWS managed ElastiCache service, so I do not have access to the other side's ssl configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the ssl handshake error is a side-effect of a race-condition bug in ioredis.

I have been banging my head over the same issue the last several days (ioredis version 4.0.0). I just couldn't reliably connect ioredis to our elasticache cluster. I would see the same intermittent error.

> Error: 140618195700616:error:140940E5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl
>   handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1216:

You can view ioredis debug output by setting "DEBUG=ioredis:*" in your node environment. Once I did this I could see that when the error occurred it was accompanied by several messages similar to the following:

> 2018-10-06T18:24:38.287Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Disconnect
>   xxx.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379 because the node does not hold any
>   slot

I tried node-redis and redis-clustr it works fine with elasticache.